# What is the ideal solution to fit the width of the text in my input?

Tags: html, css

I have this short sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/jojrspo5/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="select-style6">
        <select name="emailtemplate" onchange="uploadtemplatecode(this.value);">
            <option value="0">Choose an email template</option>
            <option value="2">Email sent to pacient exercise</option>
            <option value="5">Email sent to patient account create</option>
            <option value="8">created from repo</option>
            <option value="9">Happy birthday</option>
            <option value="10">template with image that really works</option>
            <option value="11">Appointment Template</option>
            <option value="12">Appointment Reminder</option>
            <option value="13">Credit Card Expiration Reminder</option>
            <option value="14">Credit Card Succesfull Charge</option>
            <option value="15">Credit Card Payment Declined</option>
            <option value="16">New practitioner Account</option>
            <option value="17">New Patient Email</option>
            <option value="18">New message to practitioner</option>
            <option value="19">Referall Template</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.select-style6 {
    background-image: url("/public/images/arrow-field.png"), linear-gradient(to right, white 79%, white 70%, gray 71%, lightgray 71%, lightgray 100%);
    background-position: 149px center, center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 183px;
    height: 33px;
}

.select-style6 select {
    padding: 10px 8px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.select-style6 select:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

As you can see, the text is too long and comes looks ugly.
What I want to do is add the text below so it only looks ugly.

Can you please tell me which is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of this class to make the text fits correctly :

```
.select-style6 {
    background-image: url("/public/images/arrow-field.png"), linear-gradient(to right, white 79%, white 70%, gray 71%, lightgray 71%, lightgray 100%);
    background-position: 149px center, center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 265px; /* that width change */
    height: 33px;
}
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/jojrspo5/3/)

Comment: Not wanting to increase the width of the input ... must be exactly as it is now
There another solution?

Comment: I don't think you can have a multi-line option with only html / css.. Can you use javascript / jQuery ?